# QTip show my ajax content before downloading all the content

Tags: javascript, jquery, qtip

I am using QTip in my project and I have a very frustrating problem.

I have a page which contains around 20 elements. while standing over them, qtip generate an ajax request and get additional details on these elements while showing them in a qtip.

The problem is that it seems the qtip show the tip before downloading all the content of the additional page and causing weird artifacts. This happen the first time for each additional content. second time it shows the tip there is no problem.

Here is how I am calling qtip :

```
        $(".challenge_button").each(function (index, domEle)
    {
       $(domEle).qtip({
            content: {
                url: '/main/challenge_get_info/' + $(this).data("challenge-id") +'/'
            },
            position: {
                adjust: { x: -50, y: -10, screen: true },
                corner: {
                    target: 'bottomRight',
                    tooltip: 'topLeft'
                }
            },
            style: {
                name: $(this).data("state"),
                width: {
                    max: 500,
                    min: 370
                },
                tip: true
            },
            show: {
                    ready: false,
                    delay: 500,
                    effect:
                        {type : 'fade', length : 400 }
                }
        });
    });
```

Comment: i would do  a `getJSON` to retrieve all tips contents at once before instantiating the plugin in the callback (would be probably faster as well as eliminate the problem)

Comment: Do you mean avoidng the Ajax call by qtip ? The data is html and not Json btw.

Comment: yes, in which case it would also be faster to send json (gzipped) from the server than html  & let your js parse the data into html for your qtip content

Comment: Anyway, I tried that but it didnt solve the problem. seems it not relate to loading but building the qtip frame. qtip does have a preload feature but for some reason it does not help. anyway I have moved the jqueryUI tooltip and problem solved.